# System.Runtime.Extensions Injection Errors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dependency-injection, .net-4.6.2

I'm running into an error which seems to be a combination of three factors, and I'm trying to find out if this is a known issue, and if there is a fix or work-around for it.

Factor 1: We are using Visual Studio 2015, update 3.

Factor 2: We are using .net 4.6.2.  This version of .net is not included in VS2015, so it was added via the Developer Pack link, located here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Factor 3: We are using Microsoft.Extensions.Dependency Injection.  Version 1.0.0, but the issue is reproducible in every version except 2.0.0, which does not appear to be compatible with .net 4.6.2

In order to most easily reproduce this, I am able to create a new solution in Visual Studio 2015, with a new empty web application project, targeting 4.6.2.  I open the Nuget package manager, find Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, and include version 1.0.0 in my project.  Build the project, and get this error:

[image: Visual Studio Error]

> Error CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'c:\Projects\DITest\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions.4.1.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  If I build targeting 4.6.1 it works fine, but we have other dependencies which necessitate 4.6.2.  I do not currently have access to Visual Studio 2017, but if it turns out that necessary to make this code run properly, I can pursue it.

Every avenue I've explored regarding this has ended up in a dead-end.